# Batch-wise function to account for diagonal elements in multi-dimensional matrix in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I have two numpy matrices like so:

```
matrix_a = np.random.random((2, 3))
matrix_b = np.random.random((2, 3, 5))
```

Using the following function, I am producing a diagonal matrix for each element in axis 1 of `matrix_a`:

```
def foo(M):
  b = np.zeros((M.shape[0], M.shape[1], M.shape[1]))
  diag = np.arange(M.shape[1])
  b[:, diag, diag] = M
  return b
```

I am also expanding the dimensions of `matrix_a` like so:

```
diag_mixed_alignments = np.expand_dims(diag_mixed_alignments, axis=1)
```

The shape of `matrix_a` will then become `(2, 1, 3, 3)`.

Suppose that size 2 of the 0th dimension represents the batch size. I want for each batch, to perform the following:

```
    for row in range(0, diag_mixed_alignments.shape[0]):
      cur_M = diag_mixed_alignments[row, :]
      cur_V = values[row, :]

      intmd_op1 = np.sum(np.matmul(cur_V.T, cur_M), axis=2)

      op1.append(intmd_op1)
```

The above will produce a matrix of shape `(2, 1, 5)`

My goal is to perform the same operation in tensorflow, so that I can account for the diagonal matrices created in `matrix_a` **not in an iterative manner**. What would be the equivalent set of operations to achieve this?